# Variables de session php desde diferentes dispositivos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios, tpv

Tengo estas páginas `php` código (sólo el código importante)

La primera es la que valida y guarda la información en variables de sesiones (aquí todo esta ok), ahora si escogió método tarjeta lo envia al **redsys**

```
if (isset($_POST['tarjeta'])) {
       include 'redsys.php';
 }
```

La segunda es el **redsys.php**, es la que presta el servicio y me lleva a **conexion** si sale bien y **fail** si sale mal, en **fail** sólo dice: fallo en la compra

```
session_start();
  $amount = $_SESSION['totalcomp'];


    include "tpv/apiRedsys.php";
    $miObj = new RedsysAPI;


    $url_tpv = 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago';
    $version = "HMAC_SHA256_V1";
    $clave = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //poner la clave SHA-256 facilitada por el banco 

    $name = 'INFO SUPUESTO CLIENTE';
    $code = '111111';
    $terminal = '0';
    $order = date('ymdHis');
    $amount = $amount * 100;
    $currency = '874';
    $consumerlng = '455';
    $transactionType = '8';
    $urlMerchant = 'http://MIPAGINA.es/';
    $urlweb_ok = 'http://MIPAGINA.es/conexion.php';
    $urlweb_ko = 'http://MIPAGINA.es/fail.php';

    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT", $amount);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY", $currency);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER", $order);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE", $code);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL", $terminal);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE", $transactionType);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL", $urlMerchant);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLOK", $urlweb_ok);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLKO", $urlweb_ko);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTNAME", $name);
    $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CONSUMERLANGUAGE", $consumerlng);

    $params = $miObj->createMerchantParameters();
    $signature = $miObj->createMerchantSignature($clave);

    ?>

    <form id="realizarPago" action="<?php echo $url_tpv; ?>" method="post">
        <input type='hidden' name='Ds_SignatureVersion' value='<?php echo $version; ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Ds_MerchantParameters' value='<?php echo $params; ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Ds_Signature' value='<?php echo $signature; ?>'>
    </form>
    <p>Un momento por favor...</p>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#realizarPago").submit();
    });
    </script>
```

Si está bien el pago, **conexion.php** tiene esto y me lleva a una página que sólo dice: gracias por la compra

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION["carrito"])) {


    header('Location: http://www.mipagina.com/index.php');

         }else{

    include 'includes/cliente.php';
include 'includes/domicilio.php';


    header('Location: http://www.mipagina.com/compra.php');

        }

     ?>
```

Y la **bd** la tengo así:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conexion = new mysqli('datos conexion','datos conexion', 'datos conexion', 'datos de conexion');
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
  die('lo siento hubo un problema con el servidor');
} else {
$total=0;
 if(!empty($_SESSION["carrito"])){

     $nombre =  $_SESSION['nombres'];
       $email =  $_SESSION['emails'];
       $telefono = $_SESSION['telefonos'];
       $fechapedido=$_SESSION['fechas'];
       $total=$_SESSION['totalcomp'];
       $fecha_hora_actual = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$prueba = array($nombres,$emails,$telefonos,$fechapedidos,$fecha_hora_actual);


$statement = $conexion-> prepare("INSERT INTO cliente(id,nombres,emails,telefonos,fechas,fechapedido) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$statement->bind_param('ississ',$id,$nombre,$email,$telefono,$fechapedido,$fecha_hora_actual);

$statement->execute();


 }
}

 ?>
```

Lo pruebo en varias partes y va todo perfecto, pero hay algunos casos que no me escribe nada en la **bd**, por qué podría ser? tiene algo que ver los dispositivos en que lo pruebe??? qué debería de cambiar?? por qué las variables de **session** no las registra en algunos dispositivos y cómo solucionarlo?